# Finding the turning point of a parabola

Tags: conic-sections

I know how to find the turning point of a parabola in most equations but I'm not sure how to solve it in this form, if anyone can help me please do!
$$y=x^2+4x-5$$
Thanks

Comment: Hint: Complete the square.

Comment: The vertex of the quadratic of form $ax^2+bx+c=0$ Can be found by letting $x$ equal $-\frac {b}{2a}$

Comment: I'm curious what aspect of this problem is giving you problems!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$x^2 + 4x - 5 = (x^2 + 4x + 4) - 4 - 5 = (x + 2)^2 - 9.$$

Therefore, the vertex is at $(-2, \, -9)$.

Answer (score 1):

The vertex can be found by plugging $x$ with $-\frac {b}{2a}$ give the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$.

So with your example $x^2+4x-5=0$, we have $$a=1\\b=4\\c=-5\tag{1}$$
So $-\frac {b}{2a}=-\frac {4}{2}=-2$. Plugging that into the quadratic gives $$f(-2)=4-8-5=-9\tag{2}$$
Therefore, the vertex is $(-2,-9)$.